# Multi-site email relay based on email address (in AD?)

Tags: email, smtp

We have a multi site setup currently based around Exchange 2003, but we are getting a lot of traffic over the vpn as only one server has an internet facing IP.

Is there such a product that could sit on a hosted rack somewhere that would look at an incoming email and from information in AD determine which mail server to relay the message to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, doable. But you will have to upgrade to Exchange 2010 - seriously. 2007 / 2010 are all about distributed storage architectures, having a mail procesing backbone, distributed storage etc.

Comment: We are actually just looking to move to Exchange 2007 :( Typical!

Comment: Good enough - 2007 did introduce the new architecture and it is a HUGH step. Distributing mailboxes is "just natural" with 2007 upward.

Answer (score 3):

Sendmail is able to do this with the LDAP Routing feature.

Comment: +1 mailRoutingAddress looks to be quite interesting, this has opened up a lot more search possibilites, thanks